# Clicking on a link in the preview screen crashes Android app

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, android-app, markdown-preview

App version: 1.0.31 /1.0.52
Device: Nexus 7/ Moto G
Problem: If you try click on a link in the preview screen when creating a question, the app crashes.
Logcat:

```
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.PrettyWebView$1.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(PrettyWebView.java:170)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:261)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:363)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
04-27 02:51:07.673 E/AndroidRuntime(21482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This is still happening on V1.0.52

Comment: Not repro'd on v1.0.84 beta. Might be related? [“Open in browser” crashes when Android app is set as default](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273486/open-in-browser-crashes-when-android-app-is-set-as-default?rq=1)