# "Open in browser" crashes when Android app is set as default

Tags: bug, android-app

*This is a follow-up to ["Open in browser" does nothing when Android app is set as default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216419/open-in-browser-does-nothing-when-android-app-is-set-as-default).*

> When I click a link to an SE site in the Android app, it gives me an "open with" pop-up that has two options:
>
> - Chrome
> - Stack Exchange
>
> I can then choose to open SE posts like this "Just once" or "Always."
>
> The problem is that when I set the SE app to "always," and I click "open in browser,"

Except, the app crashes when trying to open it in browser.

**LogCat** (just right after selecting "Open in browser")

```
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064): Process: com.stackexchange.marvin, PID: 16064
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.utils.Helpers.getNonMarvinViewIntent(Helpers.java:452)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.QuestionDialog$1.onClick(QuestionDialog.java:39)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1108)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3066)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3903)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-22 18:03:36.354: E/AndroidRuntime(16064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I suspect it's related to [how the `Intent` was created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259743/241919), but not sure.

Specs:

- Device model: Nexus 5
- Android version: Android 6.0.1
- SE app version: 1.0.82 (beta)
- Installed browser: Chrome 47.0.2526.83 (latest at current writing)

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround, you can prevent the Android OS from automatically loading SE content in the Stack Exchange app.  This will prevent the bug from being triggered. To do so, modify the *Go to supported URLs* setting as follows:

1. In Android's Application Manager, select the **Stack Exchange** app
2. Touch **Set as default**
3. Touch **Go to supported URLs**
4. Select **Always Ask** or **In other app**

*Tested on Android Marshmallow*

<strike>Unfortunately, employing this workaround sacrifices the ability to click any link that points to a Stack Exchange site and have it open in the app.</strike> With this setting enabled, you can still open a question in the SE app from the browser by touching the bar above the post that says **Read this post in our app!**:

[image]

**Note:** You must be viewing the mobile site to see this option.

If you would rather use your browser anyway, posts should show on the Mobile site which is easy to navigate. If you need to switch between the mobile and full sites, use the **mobile** and **full site** links at the bottom of the page.