# Android app crashes when clicking a link in Preview mode

Tags: bug, android-app, hyperlinks

While using android mobile application found a bug in it, also had an email redirecting me here to post question and drive solution finding process

*Here goes some information about this issue:*

**Env :** Android 8.1, Xiaomi Redmi 6

**Preconditions :** Login as user into android mobile app

**Steps-to-reproduce:**

1. Start creating new question (tap on ask question UI)
2. Add link with add-link-icon  without "title" as in dialog with
   example
3. Edit description in question message(optional step)
4. Tap "Preview"
5. Tap on underlined link
6. List item

**Actual Result :**
App crashed

**Expected result :**
 Link opens

Hope that will help to solve the problem!

Comment: No repro on Nexus 5, Android 7.1, SE App 1.0.96 beta. However, this might be a duplicate of [“Open in browser” crashes when Android app is set as default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273486) instead.